# libelf by example missing vis.h header

Tags: c, elf

I was wondering if anybody here is familiar with the "libelf by example" book.https://www.dbooks.org/libelf-by-example-1587/read/ 
I was trying to run prog2.c but I couldn't find the header vis.h (header it's used in chapter 3 and 5)
I downloaded the libelf library from the sourceforge link [https://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/wiki/Home/](https://www.dbooks.org/libelf-by-example-1587/read/) I also tried to googled it up but I couldn't find anything relevant. I was wondering if it's been substituted by another header in future versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I couldn't find the header vis.h

The author appears to be using [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/vis) `vis` function.

Try changing `#include <vis.h>` to `#include <bsd/vis.h>`.

On my system, this file comes from `libbsd-dev` package. It is likely that you'll need to link against `libbsd.so` to get the definition of `vis`.

Comment: I installed libbsd-dev and modified the header to #include <bsd/vis.h>. That fixed the problem. I also noticed I didn't install the library correctly. I got another problem but I'll open up another thread. Thanks